# Can we create a subset of factor variables with nlevels more than a value in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, filtering, random-forest, r-factor

I'm trying to run a random forest on a set of variables. Most of the variables are categorical (factor), and some have a lot of values. My dataset has ~1500 variables, and i'll like to drop those which have >50 categories.

Is it possible to do this in R?

Edit: I've been trying to codify this:

If the variable is factor, calculate number of nlevels. if nlevels >50, drop.

Comment: Certainly doable. You'd want to first count the number of unique values per (categorical) variable, then remove those variables with more values than your threshold. Though it's hard to give an example of exactly how to do it without knowing how your data is structured.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something using the function `nlevels` to retrieve the number of levels per column. Here's an example using `mtcars` where all columns are converted into factors and where we only keep factors having less than 10 levels.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- as.data.frame(sapply(mtcars, as.factor))

good.columns <- names(df)[sapply(df, nlevels) < 10]

filtered.df <- df %>% select(good.columns)
```

**N.B:** in your case, it would also work with non-factor columns as non-factor columns would have a number of levels equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>%
      mutate_all(factor) %>% # just to change all columns to `factor` for testing
      select_if(~nlevels(.)  < 10)
```